# Is it possible to open bootstrap dropdown on top of overflow div?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3 dropdown inside a modal. The problem is that when I open the dropdown, the dropdown menu is clipped by the end of the modal div, like this:

[image: Problem]

Is it possible to assign the parent container of the dropdown menu like some plugins like selectize or bootstrap select. Or is there any other way to make that dropdown on top of the modal?

Comment: "Or is there any other way to make that dropdown on top of the modal?" - you could try adjusting the z-index of the drop down element

Comment: You could use CSS to set the z-index values for those elements. Don't forget to set the position for both, otherwise it might not work ("relative" I believe, in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You want to be overriding bootstrap's overflow rules for the modal, which are:

```
.modal {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Perhaps give your modal an ID value and define a a rule like:

```
#yourID.modal {
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Comment: I do need scroll in my modal

Comment: I've edited my answer, so it will only show overflow on the x axis, overflow on the y axis will scroll as normal

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is solving...
Try This..

```
.dropdown-menu{
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```